# VueJS: Pass any unknown props to child component just like v-bind="$props"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to receive any props bind by the parent component into the child component without mentioning in `props:[]` because I don't know which props will bind.

Parent component

```
<template>
  <div id="parentComponent">
    <child-component v-bind="anyPropsToPass"></child-component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import ChildComponent from './components/child-component/child-component'

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
      ChildComponent
    },
    data () {
      return {
        anyPropsToPass: {
          name: 'John',
          last_name: 'Doe',
          age: '29',
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Child component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>I am {{name}} {{last_name}} and i am {{age}} old</p>
    <another-child v-bind="$props"></another-child> <!-- another child here and we pass all props -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import AnotherChild from "../another-child/another-child";
  export default {
    components: {AnotherChild},
    props: [],   // I know if I mentioned props here I can receive but it's unknown, I 
                 //just want to pass it down until it received in right component to use  
    created() {
       console.log("Props", this.$props); 
       // Gets null
       // Expected : anyPropsToPass Object
    }
  }
</script>
```

If props are mentioned in the props of child then it works but there should be some way to know which are the props passed or bind from the parent even though we are not interested in child.

e.g. Working fine!

Child component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>I am {{name}} {{last_name}} and i am {{age}} old</p>
    <another-child v-bind="$props"></another-child>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import AnotherChild from "../another-child/another-child";
  export default {
    components: {AnotherChild},
    props: ['name', 'last_name'],    
    created() {
       console.log("Props", this.$props); 
       // Gets expected props here
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.$attrs` to get all v-bind props, including undeclared props.

```js
<!-- parent  -->
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ChildComp :prop1="114" prop2="514" class="homo" />
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
// child component
export default {
  created() {
    console.log('all props: ', this.$attrs) // { "prop1": 114, "prop2": "514" }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with `this.$attrs`

Child.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>I am {{getValue('name')}} {{getValue('last_name')}} and i am {{getValue('age')}} old</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods:{
    getValue(propertyName){
      return this.$attrs[propertyName];
    }
  },
  components: {},
  props: [],
  created() {
    console.log("Props", this.$attrs);
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Drilling down the props is a bad pattern, which can lead to inconsistency, try to use the [provide/inject](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Dependency-Injection) pattern to pass data from grandparent component to the grandchild one :

```html
<template>
  <div id="parentComponent">
    <child-component></child-component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import ChildComponent from './components/child-component/child-component'

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
      ChildComponent
    },
  provide () {
     return {
       user: this.user
     }
   },
    data () {
      return {
        user: {
          name: 'John',
          last_name: 'Doe',
          age: '29',
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

in grandchild component :

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>I am {{user.name}} {{user.last_name}} and i am {{user.age}} old</p>
    <another-child></another-child>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import AnotherChild from "../another-child/another-child";
  export default {
    components: {AnotherChild},
    inject:['user'],
    created() {
       console.log("injected user", this.user); 
       
    }
  }
</script
```